# Python3 - Spellcheck txt file - replace values and preserve formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider below .txt file: `myfile.txt`:

```
Box-No.: DK10-95794
Total Discounts          USD 1,360.80
Totat:                   usp 529.20
```

As you can see, in above text file there is two errors `totat` and `usp` (should be `total` and `usd`)

Now, I am using a Python package built upon SymSpell, called [SymSpellPy](https://github.com/mammothb/symspellpy). This can check a word and determine if it's spelled incorrectly.

This is my Python script:

```
    # maximum edit distance per dictionary precalculation
    max_edit_distance_dictionary = 2
    prefix_length = 7

    # create object
    sym_spell = SymSpell(max_edit_distance_dictionary, prefix_length)

    # load dictionary
    dictionary_path = os.path.join(
        os.path.dirname(__file__), "Dictionaries/eng.dictionary.txt")

    term_index = 0  # column of the term in the dictionary text file
    count_index = 1  # column of the term frequency in the dictionary text file


    with open("myfile.txt", "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            for word in re.findall(r'\w+', line):
                # word by word
                input_term = word

                # max edit distance per lookup
                max_edit_distance_lookup = 2
                suggestion_verbosity = Verbosity.CLOSEST  # TOP, CLOSEST, ALL
                suggestions = sym_spell.lookup(input_term, suggestion_verbosity,
                                               max_edit_distance_lookup)

                # display suggestion term, term frequency, and edit distance
                for suggestion in suggestions:
                    word = word.replace(input_term, suggestion.term)

                    print("{}, {}". format(input_term, word))
```

Running above script on my text file, gives me this output:

```
Total, Total
USD, USD
Totat, Total
```

As you can see, it correctly catches the last word `totat => total`.

My question is - how can I find mispelled words and correct them **in** a txt file?

Comment: Turn it into a string, pass string through your function then write over original file.

Comment: But I need to preserve the layout of the file (spaces and linebreaks)